# Programmatically optimizing parameters in WEKA

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

I am trying to use a RBF Kernel and apply a grid-search on my LIBSVM classifier

How can i, in JAVA-Code, set multiple values for -G implying a cross validation?

Like described [here](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Optimizing+parameters)

Having a LibSVM-Object i set various values for gamma in a loop and evaluate the model. Then i use the best performing.

Is "grid search" doing anything else?